# Delete Partitioned Table

Tags: dolphindb

How to delete data from partitioned table in DolphinDB? I tried to use delete command, but it will throw exception.

It is not allowed to delete rows from tables other than basic in-memory tables and segmented in-memory tables.

Comment: Why not share more details, like the exception message?

Answer (score 0):

It is not allowed to delete some rows in a non-memory table. Instead, you can drop the whole partition and rewrite new values to the partition.